# Python - Take parts of a txt file and put them in another txt

Tags: python, regex

I have a large file with the following syntax:

```
Object 1:
[Useless Data]
com_pos = number number number
[Useless Data]

Object 2:
[Useless Data]
com_pos = number, number, number
[Useless Data]
...
and so on (there's a very large number of objects.).
```

What I want to do is pick the numbers and put them in another txt file with a specific format (basically a row for each object and a column for each number).

The problem is I have the same `com_pos =` for every object.
How should I do that? Should I use Regular Expressions?

Comment: Regex would be a good choice yes

Comment: Is the separator between the numbers always the same, or can it vary? I ask, since the numbers for `Object 1` are separated by spaces, while those for `Object 2` are separated by commas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write *some* kind of parser for this. You don't need to use regular expressions if you don't understand them. For example, given your two examples, this would work just as well:

```
with open(path) as f:
    for line in f:
        columns = line.split()
        if columns[0] == 'com_pos' and columns[1] == '=':
            numbers = [float(column.rstrip(',')) for column in columns[2:]]
            # do something with numbers
```

---

Using regular expressions can make things more compact, more efficient, or more robust. For example, consider this:

```
r = re.compile(r'com_pos\s*=\s*(\d+),?\s*(\d+),?\s*(\d+)')
with open(path) as f:
    for line in f:
        m = r.search(line)
        if m:
            numbers = [float(group) for group in m.groups]
            # do something with numbers
```

That will probably run faster, and it's more robust in the face of variable input (a data format that sometimes has commas and sometimes doesn't looks a lot like a human-written file…), and it's simpler if you understand the regexp. But if you don't, it'll be harder to maintain.

---

```
com_pos\s*=\s*(\d+),?\s*(\d+),?\s*(\d+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/u-143IJ4RGF2MYZ-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following  :

```
with open ('first_file' ,'r') as f1 and open('second_file' ,'w') as f2 :
 for line in f1.readlines() :
    if 'com_pos' in line :
       f2.write(line.split('=')[1])
```

first you need to find the line that `com_pos` is in it , then you can split that line with `=` and write the second splited element that is the numbers in second file .